# Drupal 7 views taxonomy Simple Hierarchical exposed filter

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm using Simple Hierarchical Select module for taxonomy in a profile page. The taxonomy is for a list of countries and their regions. The taxonomy hierarchy looks something like:-

**United Kingdom**
-London & South East
-South West
-Midlands
-East Anglia
**United States**
-Floida
-California
-New York

I want to display the taxonomy in views as exposed filters. Is it possible to expose the upper/first levels of the taxonomy as one filter and the second level of the taxonomy as another exposed filter so that is possible to search by country and then by region of said country?

Comment: did you get answer dude? I am also looking for same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can choose at filters: Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth; Simple hierarchical select) and set up the Depth to 1. If you select United Kingdom all child terms will show up.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because "Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth; Simple hierarchical select) and set up the Depth to 1", is only available by content views, not with taxonomy or users views.

Answer (score 0):

In field setting of that field you can check "Render Views filters as select list " and in views, that field from content can be used as expose filter as "Simple Hierarchal Select".